# Why is my C program not reading my input file?

Tags: c

I need my program to read an input file, count all the characters and print out to an output file the number of each vowel. I have the math and output file set up correctly, but I do not know why it is not reading from my input file.

I tried using this code:

```
FILE* fin = fopen("vowelsin.txt","r");
FILE* fout = fopen("vowelsout.txt","w");

char c;
int n=1,a=0,e=0,i=0,o=0,u=0;

while(fscanf(fin,"%c",&c)!=EOF){
    fscanf(fin,"%c",&c);
    if(c=='a'||c=='A'){
        a++;
```

^ it goes on to use if statements to count each character as a vowel or not.

Comment: What does the second `fscanf` do?

Comment: The character read in the `while` condition never gets counted. Use `fgetc` instead of `fscanf`.

Comment: Is there any way to properly do it with the scan function?

Comment: You don't need the & for char types.

Comment: @redwards who told you this?

Comment: @0___________ experience..  Anyway, I'm trolling you.

Comment: @redwards lack of experience? scanf ***always*** need pointer. It does not matter what type

Comment: @Mustangs26 What is `n` for? And why is it initialized to 1?

Answer (score 0):

I'll wager it's just not finding the input file if it's not ever running the loop.

I would remove one of the fscanfs, though.

```
while (fscanf(fin, "%c", &c) > 0) {
    if (c == 'a' || c == 'A') {
        a++;
. . .
```

Comment: Thank you guys :) How would I make it find the input file?

Comment: From your code, it's looking for it where your executable is.
Either way, the value in the fopen needs to point to it.
How are you compiling your code?

Comment: lol.  We've all done that.